# Insert product to database by PHP doesnt work, products do not appear

Tags: php

would you please provide a simple way to add a basic product with no image and no options and nothing, just a simple product that is inserted by PHP to the database AND appears in both front and backend. Version is 19.0.1. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Product not showing because when you add it in database , you might miss some relations in tables or entries into some tables.
So
Make php script and run it in magento root folder.
add code to create product programatically.

Comment: I have tried all codes that are found in the internet and they all dont work. Product doesnt appear in front or backend. I need a simple code that will work for sure.

Comment: By the way i use bitnami Xampp on my local machine and magento 19.0.1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
// Build the product
$product->setSku('some-sku-value-here');
$product->setAttributeSetId('some_int_value_of_some_attribute');
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setName('Some cool product name');
$product->setCategoryIds(array(7)); # some cat id's, my is 7
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, my is 1 (default frontend)
$product->setDescription('Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
$product->setPrice(39.99); # Set some price
# Custom created and assigned attributes
$product->setHeight('my_custom_attribute1_val');
$product->setWidth('my_custom_attribute2_val');
$product->setDepth('my_custom_attribute3_val');
$product->setType('my_custom_attribute4_val');
//Default Magento attribute
$product->setWeight(4.0000);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setTaxClassId(0); # My default tax class
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 99999
));
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
try {
    $product->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Handle the error
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Its just not working, product is not appearing in front or backend. Message is shown: One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated. I added that on top:$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');. I commented out the setstockdata as its trowing an error. Attribute set id i changed to 3. This all looks correct. Doesnt throw an error but product doesnt appear no where? Please help. Thanks. Using Bitnami Xampp is that maybe the problem?

Comment: If i keep the setstockdata line it shows this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '68-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'